# Make label background color occupy all height of div

Tags: html, css

I want the "Delete video" text to remain centered while its background color occupies all the height of the div container.

This is the code I have. At this moment, "delete--label" is centered and at right position (which is well), but its background doesn't fit all the div height.

```css
.delete--label {
  background-color: #f53d3d;
  color: #ffffff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.user--item-header {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #3f3f3f;
}

.user--item-content {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./user.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="user--item-header">
    SELECTED VIDEO
    <label class="delete--label">Delete Video</label>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove padding `.user--item-header` `top` & `bottom`, Add `line-height`

```
.user--item-header {
  padding: 0px 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #3f3f3f;
  line-height:45px;
}
```

```css
.delete--label {
  background-color: #f53d3d;
  color: #ffffff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.user--item-header {
  padding: 0px 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #3f3f3f;
  line-height:45px;
}

.user--item-content {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./user.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="user--item-header">
    SELECTED VIDEO
    <label class="delete--label">Delete Video</label>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for